# Copy to new branch SVN does nothing

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch

I am trying to create a new branch in SVN Repo Browser.

Here is what I did

1. Open repo browser
2. Right click on existing branch
3. Click Copy to and enter new branch name
4. Repo browser gives loading symbol for a while and does nothing ( no new branch created)

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is silly. But after refreshing multiple times to no good avail, I just closed and re-opened repo browser. New branch created!!